# How to virtualize snapshot clone fast ubuntu iso files to test if bugs are gone? What is lightest container app?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, clone, container, snapshot

How to virtualize snapshot clone fast ubuntu iso files to test if bugs are gone? What is lightest container app?

I want to fast load in ubuntu and windows an iso of ubuntu to test bugs. What is best option?

Comment: Why not just look at the `changelogs`? They're flat text files that accompany the kernel? If you have reported the bug (`man ubuntu-bug`) and gotten a problem number, `grep` can easily find it (or not) in a change log.

Comment: @waltinator want to test on running iso and running installed machines. what is best fastest apps?